# Using Quantlib to calculate the Zspread of a treasury bond is returning a type mismatch or number of arguments issue, not sure why?

Tags: python, quantlib

This is the relevant part of my code:

```
def calculate_z_spread_ql(market_price, coupon_rate, maturity_date, yield_curve_handle, issue_date, leg):
    """
    Calculate Z-spread using QuantLib with specified calendar and day count.
    """
    calendar = ql.UnitedStates(ql.UnitedStates.GovernmentBond)
    settlement_days = 2
    face_value = 100
    day_count = ql.ActualActual(ql.ActualActual.Bond)


    #maturity_ql_date = ql.Date(maturity_date.day, maturity_date.month, maturity_date.year)
    tenor = ql.Period(ql.Semiannual)

    coupons = [coupon_rate]


    schedule = ql.Schedule(issue_date, maturity_date, tenor, calendar, 
                           ql.Unadjusted, ql.Unadjusted, ql.DateGeneration.Backward, False)
    bond = ql.FixedRateBond(settlement_days, face_value, schedule, coupons, day_count)
    bond.setPricingEngine(ql.DiscountingBondEngine(yield_curve_handle))

    settlement_date = ql.Settings.instance().evaluationDate

    includeSettlementDateFlows = True

    #Error here, not sure why, all parameters are set up properly

    z_spread = ql.CashFlows.zSpread(
        leg,  # Cash flows of the bond
        market_price,       # Market price of the bond
        yield_curve_handle,  # Yield curve handle
        day_count,           # Day count convention
        ql.Compounded,       # Compounding method (optional, default: Simple)
        ql.Semiannual,        # Frequency of compounding (optional, default: Annual)
        includeSettlementDateFlows,  # Include settlement date flows (optional, default: False)
        settlement_date
    ) * 10000  # Convert to basis points

    return z_spread

################################################ Main script ######################################################################

isin = 'US912810TX63'  # Example 30yr ISIN

#global evaluation date is set to today
today = ql.Date().todaysDate()
ql.Settings.instance().evaluationDate = today

market_price, coupon_rate, maturity_date, issue_date, leg = fetch_bond_details_and_leg(isin)

maturities, yields = fetch_current_SOFR_yields()


yield_curve_handle = setup_quantlib_yield_curve(maturities, yields)

#This is for debugging only, curve set properly
print('################### cf in leg #######################')
for cf in leg:  # Directly iterate over the leg to print details of each cash flow
    print(f"Cash flow date: {cf.date()}, amount: {cf.amount()}")

print('################### maturities #######################')
print(maturities)
print('################### yields #######################')
print(yields)
print('################# yield_curve_handle #########################')
print_curve_details(yield_curve_handle)

print('################# z-spread calculations #########################')

z_spread = calculate_z_spread_ql(market_price, coupon_rate, maturity_date, yield_curve_handle, issue_date, leg)
```

What am I misssing?

I printed all the relevant inputs to the quantlib zpsread function as shown above and still something's not working in either the type or number of arguments, yet I think I set everything up correctly. ChatGPT not figuring it out either.

Here's the output with errors:

```
################### cf in leg #######################
Cash flow date: August 15th, 2024, amount: 2.124999999999999
Cash flow date: February 18th, 2025, amount: 2.124999999999999
Cash flow date: August 15th, 2025, amount: 2.124999999999999
Cash flow date: February 17th, 2026, amount: 2.124999999999999
Cash flow date: August 17th, 2026, amount: 2.124999999999999
Cash flow date: February 16th, 2027, amount: 2.124999999999999
Cash flow date: August 16th, 2027, amount: 2.124999999999999
Cash flow date: February 15th, 2028, amount: 2.124999999999999
Cash flow date: August 15th, 2028, amount: 2.124999999999999
Cash flow date: February 15th, 2029, amount: 2.124999999999999
Cash flow date: August 15th, 2029, amount: 2.124999999999999
Cash flow date: February 15th, 2030, amount: 2.124999999999999
Cash flow date: August 15th, 2030, amount: 2.124999999999999
Cash flow date: February 18th, 2031, amount: 2.124999999999999
Cash flow date: August 15th, 2031, amount: 2.124999999999999
Cash flow date: February 17th, 2032, amount: 2.124999999999999
Cash flow date: August 16th, 2032, amount: 2.124999999999999
Cash flow date: February 15th, 2033, amount: 2.124999999999999
Cash flow date: August 15th, 2033, amount: 2.124999999999999
Cash flow date: February 15th, 2034, amount: 2.124999999999999
Cash flow date: August 15th, 2034, amount: 2.124999999999999
Cash flow date: February 15th, 2035, amount: 2.124999999999999
Cash flow date: August 15th, 2035, amount: 2.124999999999999
Cash flow date: February 15th, 2036, amount: 2.124999999999999
Cash flow date: August 15th, 2036, amount: 2.124999999999999
Cash flow date: February 17th, 2037, amount: 2.124999999999999
Cash flow date: August 17th, 2037, amount: 2.124999999999999
Cash flow date: February 16th, 2038, amount: 2.124999999999999
Cash flow date: August 16th, 2038, amount: 2.124999999999999
Cash flow date: February 15th, 2039, amount: 2.124999999999999
Cash flow date: August 15th, 2039, amount: 2.124999999999999
Cash flow date: February 15th, 2040, amount: 2.124999999999999
Cash flow date: August 15th, 2040, amount: 2.124999999999999
Cash flow date: February 15th, 2041, amount: 2.124999999999999
Cash flow date: August 15th, 2041, amount: 2.124999999999999
Cash flow date: February 18th, 2042, amount: 2.124999999999999
Cash flow date: August 15th, 2042, amount: 2.124999999999999
Cash flow date: February 17th, 2043, amount: 2.124999999999999
Cash flow date: August 17th, 2043, amount: 2.124999999999999
Cash flow date: February 16th, 2044, amount: 2.124999999999999
Cash flow date: August 15th, 2044, amount: 2.124999999999999
Cash flow date: February 15th, 2045, amount: 2.124999999999999
Cash flow date: August 15th, 2045, amount: 2.124999999999999
Cash flow date: February 15th, 2046, amount: 2.124999999999999
Cash flow date: August 15th, 2046, amount: 2.124999999999999
Cash flow date: February 15th, 2047, amount: 2.124999999999999
Cash flow date: August 15th, 2047, amount: 2.124999999999999
Cash flow date: February 18th, 2048, amount: 2.124999999999999
Cash flow date: August 17th, 2048, amount: 2.124999999999999
Cash flow date: February 16th, 2049, amount: 2.124999999999999
Cash flow date: August 16th, 2049, amount: 2.124999999999999
Cash flow date: February 15th, 2050, amount: 2.124999999999999
Cash flow date: August 15th, 2050, amount: 2.124999999999999
Cash flow date: February 15th, 2051, amount: 2.124999999999999
Cash flow date: August 15th, 2051, amount: 2.124999999999999
Cash flow date: February 15th, 2052, amount: 2.124999999999999
Cash flow date: August 15th, 2052, amount: 2.124999999999999
Cash flow date: February 18th, 2053, amount: 2.124999999999999
Cash flow date: August 15th, 2053, amount: 2.124999999999999
Cash flow date: February 17th, 2054, amount: 2.124999999999999
Cash flow date: February 17th, 2054, amount: 100.0
################### maturities #######################
[1, 2, 3, 5, 7, 10, 20, 30]
################### yields #######################
[0.050895, 0.046245, 0.043525, 0.040827, 0.039832, 0.03928, 0.038740000000000004, 0.036802]
################# yield_curve_handle #########################
Reference Date: March 17th, 2025
Year 1: Zero Rate = 0.0462, Discount Factor = 0.9548
Year 2: Zero Rate = 0.0435, Discount Factor = 0.9166
Year 3: Zero Rate = 0.0422, Discount Factor = 0.8811
Year 4: Zero Rate = 0.0408, Discount Factor = 0.8493
Year 5: Zero Rate = 0.0403, Discount Factor = 0.8174
Year 6: Zero Rate = 0.0398, Discount Factor = 0.7874
Year 7: Zero Rate = 0.0396, Discount Factor = 0.7576
Year 8: Zero Rate = 0.0395, Discount Factor = 0.7293
Year 9: Zero Rate = 0.0393, Discount Factor = 0.7022
Year 10: Zero Rate = 0.0392, Discount Factor = 0.6755
Year 11: Zero Rate = 0.0392, Discount Factor = 0.6499
Year 12: Zero Rate = 0.0391, Discount Factor = 0.6254
Year 13: Zero Rate = 0.0391, Discount Factor = 0.6018
Year 14: Zero Rate = 0.0390, Discount Factor = 0.5792
Year 15: Zero Rate = 0.0390, Discount Factor = 0.5575
Year 16: Zero Rate = 0.0389, Discount Factor = 0.5366
Year 17: Zero Rate = 0.0388, Discount Factor = 0.5166
Year 18: Zero Rate = 0.0388, Discount Factor = 0.4974
Year 19: Zero Rate = 0.0387, Discount Factor = 0.4790
Year 20: Zero Rate = 0.0385, Discount Factor = 0.4626
Year 21: Zero Rate = 0.0384, Discount Factor = 0.4469
Year 22: Zero Rate = 0.0382, Discount Factor = 0.4319
Year 23: Zero Rate = 0.0380, Discount Factor = 0.4176
Year 24: Zero Rate = 0.0378, Discount Factor = 0.4039
Year 25: Zero Rate = 0.0376, Discount Factor = 0.3909
Year 26: Zero Rate = 0.0374, Discount Factor = 0.3783
Year 27: Zero Rate = 0.0372, Discount Factor = 0.3664
Year 28: Zero Rate = 0.0370, Discount Factor = 0.3549
Year 29: Zero Rate = 0.0368, Discount Factor = 0.3440
################# z-spread calculations #########################
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "H:\Python_KS\ZSpreadTest_QuantLib_Test.py", line 188, in <module>
    z_spread = calculate_z_spread_ql(market_price, coupon_rate, maturity_date, yield_curve_handle, issue_date, leg)
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "H:\Python_KS\ZSpreadTest_QuantLib_Test.py", line 143, in calculate_z_spread_ql
    z_spread = ql.CashFlows.zSpread(
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\ProgramData\anaconda3\envs\Khalil_Python\Lib\site-packages\QuantLib\QuantLib.py", line 15020, in zSpread
    return _QuantLib.CashFlows_zSpread(*args)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
TypeError: Wrong number or type of arguments for overloaded function 'CashFlows_zSpread'.
  Possible C/C++ prototypes are:
    CashFlows::zSpread(Leg const &,Real,ext::shared_ptr< YieldTermStructure > const &,DayCounter const &,Compounding,Frequency,bool,Date,Date,Real,Size,Rate)
    CashFlows::zSpread(Leg const &,Real,ext::shared_ptr< YieldTermStructure > const &,DayCounter const &,Compounding,Frequency,bool,Date,Date,Real,Size)
    CashFlows::zSpread(Leg const &,Real,ext::shared_ptr< YieldTermStructure > const &,DayCounter const &,Compounding,Frequency,bool,Date,Date,Real)
    CashFlows::zSpread(Leg const &,Real,ext::shared_ptr< YieldTermStructure > const &,DayCounter const &,Compounding,Frequency,bool,Date,Date)
    CashFlows::zSpread(Leg const &,Real,ext::shared_ptr< YieldTermStructure > const &,DayCounter const &,Compounding,Frequency,bool,Date)
    CashFlows::zSpread(Leg const &,Real,ext::shared_ptr< YieldTermStructure > const &,DayCounter const &,Compounding,Frequency,bool)
```

Comment: Looks like an interesting question but more details on the library your using would be helpful :)

Answer (score 0):

`CashFlows.zSpread` takes a term structure as its third argument, not a handle.  If a handle is all you have available at that point, you can call `yield_curve_handle.currentLink()` to extract the contained term structure.

Comment: Thank you very much Luigi! That worked, now on to calculating this for inflation linked bonds. If you have any words of wisdom on how to do this, it would be greatly appreciated. thx